# Calling c++ object in callback function of c library

Tags: c++, c, callback

I am using a C library, which uses callback functions.

Is there any way I can access calling object of C++ class ?

**Edit:**

I am using c-client lib. 
Which have function mm_log.

```
 void mm_log(char* string, long err_flag)
```

which is getting internally called by library. I want to check on which Imap stream it is getting called.

**More Info**
you can download library from ftp://ftp.cac.washington.edu/imap

Comment: Can you provide a declaration of a function in this C library that takes a callback? A small code example of how callbacks work with this C library helps too.

Comment: @In Silico please have a look on c-client lib.

Comment: @Vivek maybe you could link to the documentation for `mm_log` rather than the entire library?

Comment: You can add a static function in the C++ class and provide it as a callback. Clumsy but will work in the circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

All (good) C library functions that want a callback have a `void* user_data` pointer as part of the function and the callback parameter. You just pass a pointer to your object as this to the function and it just gets passed back to you in the callback. Example:

```
typedef void (*callback)(void*);

void dumb_api_call(callback cb, void* user_data){
  cb(user_data);
}

struct Foo{};

void my_callback(void* my_data){
  Foo* my_foo = static_cast<Foo*>(my_data);
}

int main(){
  Foo my_foo;
  dumb_api_call(my_callback, &my_foo);
}
```

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham
I don't think that will be solved my problem as callback is getting internally called from library. I have updated my question with library and more details.

Comment: @Vivek: You're still missing the important part: *how* is it called by the library? There must be a point where you pass it to the library.

Comment: this is IMAP c library. 
I calls it like 
        imap_stream_ = mail_open(imap_stream_,"mailboxnamestring", NIL);
after that I uses all calls like 
mail_ping
mail_uid 
mail_msgno
calls from the library . 
mm_log is get  called by library when any error comes.Like tcp timeout.

Comment: hi ,  is still I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

If `mm_log` is a function which you are implementing and the library is calling (which is a terrible way for a library to do callbacks, by the way), then there is no way you can get it to reference a member function in your class.

What you could do is use a global variable which you set to point to your object before invoking the library (and clear after) and then use it within `mm_log` to invoke the desired method. This is nasty and dangerous but can work.

If you have more than one thread then exercise extreme caution - or find a better library.

Comment: yes. mm_log if function for which library is giving prototype and I am implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Code is important for such a question.  But without seeing any of your code, I can still give you a blanket statement :)

You'd have to wrap your C++ object with global functions that access a plain-old-struct, and export those with:

```
extern "C"
```

There are a plenty of caveats, but this is the gist of it.

See this FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Comment: I don't think that will be solved my problem as callback is getting internally called from library. I have updated my question with library and more details.